# Label displacement for 3.5 inch screen and 4 inch screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, interface-builder

I am developing an iPhone app and I have a few sets of labels which is fetching data from an XML feed. However, initially I designed the app for the iPhone 5 (with the bigger screen) and when I change it to 3.5 inch retina, the labels are displaced as seen in the photos.

iPhone 5 4.0 inch label
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4LXp.png

iPhone 4 3.5 inch label
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPNpn.png

Thus when clicking on the toggle button for designing for 3.5 inch and then editing it, then the 4 inch retina design will be displaced. Does anyone know how I can overcome this issue? Thanks. I am obviously using the storyboard to edit the files.

Answer (score 3):

Mikkel, it depends if you are using Autolayout or not. To check if it's enabled, go to the File Inspector (Command+Alt+1) and see if the checkbox *Use Autolayout* is on or off).

**If you are not using Autolayout**: you will need to configure the AutoResizing Masks. In order to do so, go to the Size Inspector (Command+Alt+5). Then, for **each label**, you set the left margin and the top margin as fixed (the red line, not the arrow).

**If you are using Autolayout**: in the same size inspector, configure correctly the constraints to left and top as fixed, and it should be fine.